# Running several python scripts from C#

Tags: c#, python, winforms

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me out here.  I am relatively new to C# and am trying to execute some Python code I wrote from within a C# winform app.

What I would like to do is input a name from a text box within the winform and have it process through the python scripts and return a result in another textbox on the winform.

I have found several good examples of how to execute a single script within C#, but I am having some trouble understanding how I can reference multiple scripts.

As an example,  I have one python script that references two other scripts within code

```
from FindTelephone import *
from FindAddress import *

def createPerson(name)
  telephone = FindTelephone(name)
  address = FindAddress(name)
....
```

Is there a way to have C# point to a reference of my other python scripts before running my main script?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Marshall

Comment: You may want to search for a tool called `Iron Python`

Comment: I haven't personally done this, but this looks pretty legit: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657698/Python-Visual-Studio-and-Csharp-So-Sweet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run a python script from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp)

Comment: IronPython is for using Python on the CLR, meaning you can use existing C# code/libraries in python, not the other way around.
If you want to execute a python script from C# check the question linked by @MarkyPython

Comment: @Sidewinder94 IronPython works both ways: I know from experience it will let a C# app run python, having used to allow users to enter Python code instead of having to parse mathematical expressions.

Comment: @RoadieRich Interesting, would you happen to have an example available ? There was no such functionality described in the documentation when I used it (admittedly it was a few years ago)

Comment: @Sidewinder94 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53611/Embedding-IronPython-in-a-C-Application was the tutorial I used, iirc - this would have been 2012, I think.  It was for a company I've moved on from, so no longer have access to the source.

Comment: @RoadieRich Thanks. I'll have to check what differs between PythonTools and IronPython the next time i'll have to make the tow languages interact. But it's nice to have alternatives.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 if it helps, I found an old backup of the source: https://bitbucket.org/RoadieRich/centipede

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this one out as soon as i'll have some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in these posts?: 
[Call Python function from c# (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462175/call-python-function-from-c-sharp-net), 
[run a python script from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp)?

Or

You might want to look into [pythonnet](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html).

Or

If you want an easyer way of doing this then I recommend using [Iron Python](http://ironpython.net/documentation/) in place of normal Python. IronPython is an open-source implementation of the Python programming language which is tightly integrated with the .NET Framework. Means that it is much easyer to use with C# and Windows Forms and looks almost just like normal Python.

Or

For in case you are using Visual Studio, VS has some Python tools that might help you in your quest. [Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx). You can find more documentation [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657698/Python-Visual-Studio-and-Csharp-So-Sweet) This last link is provided by Jedediah from comments so vote his comment up if you liked this last link.

Other handy link: [Integrating Python With Other Languages](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages)

Comment: [tag:IronPython] should definitely be higher in preference than calling python via Processes.  Especially if you want to return anything more than just a number or string.

Comment: Thanks all for the wonderful help and discussion!  Iron Python will get the job done.